# Why my global variable isn't seen by another function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is the most irritating problem I have ever faced:

```
var appslst = [];
function f1()
{
    chrome.management.getAll(function(lst)
    {
    appslst = lst;
    });
}

function f2() // this function isn't working!!
{
    var l = appslst.length;
    var ind = 0;
    while(ind < l)
    {
        document.getElementById("here").value = document.getElementById("here").value.concat(String(ind), ". ", appslst[ind].name, "\n");
        ind += 1;
    }
}

function f3()
{
     f1();
     f2();
}
```

I believe that `appslst` - as it's a global variable - should be seen in both functions `f1()` and `f2()`, but the above code isn't working and I have no idea why.

Also, I have tried the following code (and it's working) :

```
var appslst = [];
function f1()
{
    chrome.management.getAll(function(lst)
    {
        appslst = lst;
        var l = appslst.length;
        var ind = 0;
        while(ind < l)
        {
            document.getElementById("here").value = document.getElementById("here").value.concat(String(ind), ". ", appslst[ind].name, "\n");
            ind += 1;
        }
    });
}
```

Some more details. I'm learning how to build extension for Google Chrome.
I have download the sample: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/examples/extensions/app_launcher.zip from this link: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html. I had a look over the code and found the same code  I wrote, except that it's working!

Here's the part I'm talking about:

```
function onLoad()
{
  chrome.management.getAll(function(info)
  {
    var appCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
      if (info[i].isApp) {
        appCount++;
      }
    }
    if (appCount == 0) {
      $("search").style.display = "none";
      $("appstore_link").style.display = "";
      return;
    }
    completeList = info.sort(compareByName);
    onSearchInput();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.management.getAll` is asynchronous - hence you need to pass a function that is executed *only when Chrome is done executing `getAll`*.

This means that `f1(); f2();` will go like this:

- `f1` is called
- `getAll` is called (that's what `f1` is doing)
- `f2` is called
- iterating over `appslst` (that's what `f2` is doing)
- (some time in between)
- `getAll` is done; the function passed to it is called
- `appslst` is filled with data from `getAll` (that's what the passed function is doing)

In other words, `appslst` is still empty at the time `f2` is called. So you need to suspend `f2()` as well:

```
chrome.management.getAll(function(lst){
    appslst = lst;
    f2(); // only run when getAll is done and appslst is filled
});
```

Comment: then why the code of the sample is woking? note that `completeList` is a global variable as well. thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you mean the last code sample - they are also iterating in the function passed to `getAll`, and at that time the data you want to iterate is available.

Comment: just 2 last questions: 1. What should I do if I want the data to be copied to a global variable? 2. Is there any link to learn more?

Comment: @joker: The data is copied into the global variable `appslst` as well here. If you want to understand the main concepts of asynchronous JavaScript - there are dozens of articles about this if you do a quick Google search.